# My Android app won't update after pushing a new release to testing

Tags: android

This is my first Android App I've put on the Play Store, I've successfully released the first version of it, but I've already got things I want to update and move. When creating my new release I've tried pushing it to internal testers and open testing but get the same results.

It downloads 100% but when the play store shows 'installing' error message pops up saying can't install [app name].

The log files are very large and I can't tell if there's actually anything useful there, error code looks like -504 but searching for that I couldn't find anything helpful. How do I even go about trying to debug something like this?

Comment: can you please write in more details ? which track you published in the first time, and when the error happens

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to Play Store cache on your device:

Go to Settings > Apps & Notifications > Apps > Google Play Store > Uninstall Updates / Clear Cache (depending on your device).

Comment: I've tried this on 2 devices and it doesn't resolve the issue. I definitely think there's something in the app causing this but haven't the slightest idea why. It runs on the emulator from Android Studio.